# Post Json from android client to server and get response

Tags: android, json, rest, http-post, http-get

I'm new to android network programming and I want to post some Json formatted data from an android to a server and get response back to android client using same `HttpURLConnection` which used for post data.

**Here is my post code:**

```
    public void post() throws IOException {

    URL url = createEndpointUrl();

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String query = createQueryParameters();

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

    writer.write(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    // Here i want to get operation 
    // result (response) from server 
    .
    .
    .
    //
    os.close();

    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get response :**

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 String decodedString;
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
       stringBuilder.append(decodedString);
 }
 in.close();
 /*YOUR RESPONSE */
 String response = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: I'm just curious, Client will be waiting for getting response if server does heavy jobs?

Comment: @saber Yes, you have to show some kind of Progress.You can use AsyncTask for that.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
public void post() throws IOException {

URL url = createEndpointUrl();

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

String query = createQueryParameters();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

// Here i want to get operation 
// result (response) from server 
.
.
.
//
os.close();
try {
int responseCode =  conn.getResponseCode();// error code 
String response = ""; // response
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new          
InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
br.close();
 }catch(Exception e){
// handle error
}
conn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, What if server does heavy operation? Well, in this situation client waits for server response?

Comment: Set the connection and server timeouts first place. And this task in separate thread or asynctask( doInBackground method. ).